# Trying to set up a web server through Raspberry pi2 using apache2

Tags: raspberry-pi, apache2, raspberry-pi2

Working on trying to make my pi a web server with apache2 and have installed it properly.

When I go to load the page it gives me back this page that just says

this:

*" Index of / Name Last modified Size Description "*

Comment: What is the location of your page index file ?

Comment: i have following steps from https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu I think it would just be in the ls -l directory. @RahulKP